# Why is my application keeps crashing?

Tags: android

I am building a floating Android application with the code below.
But the app keeps crashing, and I don't know why. Can somebody please tell me what the problem is?

```
public class FloatingApp extends Service {


    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View chatHead;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        chatHead = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null, false);    


        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        try {
            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        // Get current time in nano seconds.

                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

}
```

By the way, there is no error. I edited some code that previously was for a floating image, which I changed to display a layout in window manager.

From LogCat:

> 06-28 04:13:39.145: D/AndroidRuntime(2377): Shutting down VM 06-28
>   04:13:39.149: W/dalvikvm(2377): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0xa4b8c648) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   execute method of the activity 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   06-28 04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   ... 11 more 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377): Caused by:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.firsttry/com.firsttry.MainActivity2}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
>   06-28 04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
>   06-28 04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555) 06-28
>   04:13:39.297: E/AndroidRuntime(2377):     at
>   com.firsttry.opening.moveto3(opening.java:37) 06-28 04:13:39.297:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2377):   ... 14 more 06-28 04:13:46.337:
>   I/Process(2377): Sending signal. PID: 2377 SIG: 9

Comment: Post the error from logcat here

Comment: I added it. Thanks.

Comment: Read the log first `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.firsttry/com.firsttry.MainActivity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? "

Comment: oh, I forgot to declare the activity! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this line carefully

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.firsttry/com.firsttry.MainActivity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

It says you have not declared the activity in your manifest file

You need to declare the Activity within the application tag in manifest